# How to map an object literal to be an instance of my constructor function?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have a constructor function like below:

```
var Person = function (name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
}

Person.prototype = {
    getAgePlusTwo: function () {
        return this.age + 2;
    }
}
```

I can create an object like this and access the instance methods:

```
var p1 = new Person('Person1', 22);
p1.getAgePlusTwo();
```

However I get my objects from a JSON service so I can't use `new` to create the objects. Is there any way to map an object literal like this:

```
var p2 = { name: 'Person2', age: 25 }
```

to be an instance of `Person` so I can use its instance methods like `p2.getAgePlusTwo()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can change the `Person` constructor to accept an object that keeps all the info instead of `name` and `age` params, I would do so:

**FIDDLE** http://jsfiddle.net/JPQ57/2/

**JS**

```
var Person = function (optns) {
    if(optns){
        this.name = optns.name || "";
        this.age = parseInt(optns.age) || 0;
    }
}

var json1 = {name: "Person2", age: "22"}

var p2 = new Person(json1);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This is fine for a single object, however it feels awkward to do this for thousands of objects I get from the JSON service.

Comment: sorry I don't get your point. From the JSON service you'll receive an array of info, right? like {[{name:"John", age:"25"}, {name: "Peter", age:"35"}, ...]}

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is to use the instance methods defined for Person on a given object `p2` you can simply do

```
Person.prototype.getAgePlusTwo.call(p2)
```

Provided `p2` has all the required properties that `getAgePlusTwo` uses. Also if the function takes any additional arguments they can be passed after `p2`. You can read more about `Function.prototype.call` at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to modify the constructor you can create a factory function:

```
function makePerson(json){
  return new Person(json.name,json.age);
}

var p2 = makePerson({name:'Lebowski',age:41});
p2.getAgePlusTwo();
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mXHL7/1/)

Answer (score 1):

In a generic manner, try this :

```
function parseObject(jsonObject, classToRealize) {
    var isCorrect = true;
    var comparison = new classToRealize();
    var realizedObject = Object.create(classToRealize.prototype);

    if (Object.keys(jsonObject).length === Object.keys(comparison).length) {
        for (property in comparison) {
            if (typeof(comparison[property]) != 'function') {
                if(!jsonObject.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                    isCorrect = false;
                    break;
                } else {
                  realizedObject[property] = jsonObject[property];  
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        isCorrect = false;
    }

    if (isCorrect) 
        return realizedObject;
    else
        return null;
}
```

It'll check the json for integrity of the data, and allows you to parse any object from any json data. It'll return null in case of any error. I made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9uu3g/2/) to illustrate it (it shows 4 alerts when you come to the page).