# merge two objects without adding new properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have two JSON objects that I want to merge in such a way that only the values of the properties in the first object that already exist are updated.

I want to extend the first object with the second

```
var obj1 = {a:'apple', b:'banana', c:'cucumber'};
var obj2 = {a:'aarbei', b:'beet', d:'durian'};
```

and get this result

```
{a:'aarbei', b:'beet', c:'cucumber'};
```

instead of (which I get using `$.extend`)

```
{a:'aarbei', b:'beet', c:'cucumber', d:'durian'};
```

In reality my JSON objects can be much bigger and contain nested objects/arrays of unknown complexity

Comment: why did you chose that username?! i spit my whole coffee at the wall!

Comment: to save people from the possible risks of consuming hot beverages

Comment: I'd say that's not extending but a simple overwrite of obj1 with obj2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about simple `for` loop:

```
for (var key in obj2) {
    if (key in obj1) {
        obj1[key] = obj2[key];
    }
}
```

For nested object you can wrap this code into recursive function:

```
function mergeObj(a, b) {
    for (var key in b) {
        if (key in a) {
            a[key] = typeof a[key] === 'object' && typeof b[key] === 'object' ? mergeObj(a[key], b[key]) : b[key];
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rHUM6/

Comment: This ignores the problem of nested objects/arrays

Comment: Absolutely, you should have stated it in question!

Comment: I do. Read the last line

Comment: Oh, no problem - we need recursion.

Answer (score 1):

This should work...

```
function mergeObjs () {
    for (var key in obj2) {
         if (obj1.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
             obj1[key] = obj2[key]
         }
    }
    return obj1;
}

var mergedObjs = mergeObjs();
```

Comment: This ignores the problem of nested objects/arrays

Answer (score 1):

I took a different approach, trimming the unwanted properties from a copy of each object and then using those objects to extend a new object.

```
var obj1 = {a:'apple', b:'banana', c:'cucumber'};
var obj2 = {a:'aarbei', b:'beet', d:'durian'};
var keepProps = ["a", "b", "c"];

var trimmedObj1 = trim(obj1, keepProps);
var trimmedObj2 = trim(obj2, keepProps);

var obj3 = $.extend({}, trimmedObj1, trimmedObj2);
console.log(obj3);

function trim(obj, properties){
    var copy = $.extend({}, obj);
    for(x in obj){
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(x) && properties.indexOf(x) == -1){
            delete copy[x];
        }
    }
    return copy;
}
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/m8NCc/

Comment: I like this but also doesnt take into account the nested objects/arrays

Answer (score 0):

Javascript inherintance is not so complex.

If you have an object, let's say `ObjectA` like

```
function ObjectA () {
    this.a = "Hello";
    this.a = "World";
    this.c = 30;
}
```

Then you want to inherit this object :

```
function ObjectB () {
    ObjectA.call(this);// Call the super constructor
}
ObjectB.prototype = Object.create(ObjectA.prototype); // Inheritance
ObjectB.prototype.constructor = ObjectB;
```

Finally, you can acces and/or modify any property from ObjectA like :

```
var o = new ObjectB();
o.a = "Hi";
```

If you need to parse JSON object, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21649983/how-to-map-an-object-literal-to-be-an-instance-of-my-constructor-function/21650898#21650898) (quoting myself :/).